# Where should I ask a question about cookies and privacy?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I'm wondering if there's any security/privacy benefits to managing cookies (that is, managing by deleting ones you don't want/need), but I'm not sure it's appropriate for SF.

I guess I could phrase it in the form of, "Are there any corporate benefits to wiping cookies and are there any tools to enforce a cookie policy?"  Would that be on-topic enough?

Maybe a question about whether it helps protect your privacy to delete cookies would be on-topic for Security.SE?  or Webapps?

Mostly what I'm after are SF'ers opinions on this, but as a second-best option I'd go with the opinions of another SE that SF'ers suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Security would be my first choice (in the context of "Does it make sense for me to use porn mode / wipe out my cookies, etc.?").

Webmasters would be my second choice (in the context of "Does it make sense for my site to tell the browser to discard cookies when the user logs out?").

`"Are there any tools to enforce a cookie policy?"` Would be kinda shopping, but if you change "tools" to "ways" and specify why you want to wipe them (a good reason from Security that answers the "Is there any benefit to...?" part) and the OS you're concerned about I'd consider it on-topic for here as well.

Answer (score 4):

We would accept that question at Security.